# Keeping tracking the user's location once app is closed?

Tags: android, geolocation, tracking

How can an android app keep sending data to server even it is closed (user pressed home button)?

In fact, I want to keep tracking the user's location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) that can run in the background.

Comment: Thank you for your correction, I'll try to write better next time.

Comment: Make sure you get locks on data connections and whatnot. Also, test this a lot. You will upset users both by sending the data and burning battery (assuming they're regular users, not an internal app or whatever)

Comment: @user1022254 Did you use Kevin's advice?